# How can I create a column with a running sum of the wordcount using mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following sql to combine 2 tables and then count the results

```
SELECT td.word, COUNT( instance ) AS wordcount
        FROM ws_words td
        LEFT JOIN ws_missed_words t ON ( t.wordID = td.wordID )
        WHERE quizID =1
        GROUP BY td.word
```

The results give

```
*****************************
|  word  |      wordcount   |
*****************************
|  list  |         3        |
|  miss  |         1        |
|  skip  |         1        |
| another|         0        |
```

I'd like to add one more column to this. I'd like to do a running sum of the wordcount column and put it into its own column (called total) as shown below.

**wanted results**

```
 ****************************************************
    |  word  |      wordcount   |   totalwordcount  |
    *************************************************
    |  list  |         3        |     3             |
    |  miss  |         1        |     4             |
    |  skip  |         1        |     5             |
    | another|         0        |     5             |
```

I've tried the following

```
SELECT td.word, COUNT( instance ) AS wordcount, SUM(wordcount) AS totalwordcount
FROM ws_words td
LEFT JOIN ws_missed_words t ON ( t.wordID = td.wordID )
WHERE quizID =1
GROUP BY td.word
```

but I get the error

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'wordcount' in 'field list'
```

So next I tried

```
SELECT atable.word, atable.wordcount, SUM(atable.wordcount) AS totalwordcount FROM
(SELECT td.word, COUNT( instance ) AS wordcount
FROM ws_words td
LEFT JOIN ws_missed_words t ON ( t.wordID = td.wordID )
WHERE quizID =1
GROUP BY td.word) AS atable
```

but I get something like this

```
************************************************
|  word  |      wordcount   |   totalwordcount |
************************************************
|  list  |         1        |         5        |
```

**QUESTION**

How can I create a column with a running sum of the wordcount?

**UPDATE** STRAWBERRY'S METHOD gives me the below code

---

```
|  word  |      wordcount   |   running         |
*************************************************
| another|         0        |     1             |
|  miss  |         1        |     2             |
|  skip  |         1        |     3             |
|  list  |         3        |     4             |
```

It seems to be ranking each word, so the lowest wordcount starts at 1, then if there are 2 words of equal wordcount it lists them in alphabetical order.

Comment: Still no DDLs, so I'm not going to dwell on this, but what happens if you substitute COUNT() with SUM()? Oh and you probably want to wrap my conditions in parentheses like so... `ON y.wordcount < x.wordcount OR (y.wordcount = x.wordcount AND y.word < x.word)`

Comment: I've tried wrapping it in parentheses, but it had no noticeable effect. I've played around with the code a bit, but no luck. I'm going to leave it for the moment and come back to it later when I have more time. I hear you on the DDLs, I don't know how to make them but I'll add it to my list of things to research. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Untested, 'cause you gave us nothing to test - but one way could be something like this...

```
 SELECT x.*, COUNT(*) running
   FROM
      ( SELECT td.word
                  , COUNT( t.instance ) wordcount
               FROM ws_words td
               LEFT 
               JOIN ws_missed_words t 
                 ON t.wordID = td.wordID 
              WHERE td.quizID = 1 
              GROUP 
                 BY td.word
      ) x
   JOIN
      ( SELECT td.word
             , COUNT( t.instance ) wordcount
          FROM ws_words td
          LEFT 
          JOIN ws_missed_words t 
            ON t.wordID = td.wordID 
         WHERE td.quizID = 1 
         GROUP 
            BY td.word
      ) y
     ON y.wordcount < x.wordcount
     OR y.wordcount = x.wordcount
    AND y.word < x.word
  GROUP
     BY x.word;
```

Comment: I apologise for the slow reply. I've updated my question with the results of your method and what I think is happening.